# Trace of an element in a field of order $p^n$ is in $F_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

Suppose that $F$ is a field of $p^n$ elements.

For $a\in F, $ tr (a):= $a+a^p+ a^{p^2}+...+a^{p^{n-1}}$.
Then, it is to be shown that tr(a) is in $F_p$ (finite field of order $p$).

Since $x^{p^n}-x=\Pi_{a\in F} (x-a)$, it suffices to show that tr$(a)^p=$ tr(a).

For this to be true, we must have $(a+a^p+ a^{p^2}+...+a^{p^{n-1}})^p= a^p+...+a= $tr$(a)$.

But I don't understand why that should be true as I know that if $F$ were of characteristic $p$, then we would have $(x+y)^p= x^p+y^p$. But in the above case, $F$ is not given to be of characteristic $0$.

Comment: Are you saying $F$ does not have characteristic $p$, or are you saying you don't know whether it has characteristic $p$? This is not clear to me.

Comment: @R.P. It is not given that F has characteristic $p$. So my question is: why is $(a+a^p+...+a^{p^{n-1}})^p= a^p+ (a^p)^p+...+(a^{p^{n-1}})^p$ true?

Comment: It doesn't have to be given. You can find it from the data that *are* given.

Comment: @R.P. Can you please explain how? Because if that is true then every field of order $p^n$ shall have char $p$.

Comment: Yes, that is true. The characteristic of a field is either zero or it is prime. Also the characteristic of any finite ring must divide its cardinality (one way of seeing this is noting that the set $\{1,1+1,1+1+1,\ldots\}$ is a subgroup of its underlying additive group). It follows from these two facts that the characteristic of $F$ is $p$.

Comment: @R.P. Oh yes, thanks a lot :-).

Comment: You could also refer to the prime field of $F$ (it cannot be $\mathbf{Q}$).